# How to define function in _viewImport and use in other pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to define `public static function` in `_ViewImports` and use in other pages, but build project being failed

**in _ViewImports =**

```
@using parsys
@using parsys.Models
@using parsys.Resources
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@functions  {
    public static string ReplaceSpace(string value)
    {
        return value.Trim().Replace(" ", "-");
    }
}
```

**in pages =**

```
 <a href="~/@item.Page_ID/Page/@_Views__ViewImports.ReplaceSpace(item.Page_Title)">@item.Page_Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **`@Views__ViewImports.ReplaceSpace(...)` instead of `@_Views__ViewImports.ReplaceSpace(...)`**

**Demo:**

[image]

---

By the way, you could always use `ILDASM` to inspect the `Views.dll`:

[image]

---

Finally, as a reminder, please avoid too much logics in your view files if possible.